# Sind [e] und [ɪ] Allophone?

Tags: pronunciation

Bei der Recherche zur Beantwortung einer [anderen Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/35169/1487) bemerkte ich, dass der Diphthong, der meist »ei«, seltener auch »ai«, geschrieben wird, in unterschiedlichen Nachschlagewerken unterschiedlich in der Lautschrift wiedergegeben wird.

Stellvertretend für Wörter, die diesen Diphthong enthalten, habe ich mir jenes Wort angesehen, das nur aus diesem Zwielaut besteht:

> Ei

- [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Ei): [aɪ̯]
- [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diphthong#Standard-Diphthonge): /aɪ̯/
- [adaba](http://www.adaba.at) (Leider ist kein direkter Link auf den Eintrag von »Ei« möglich)

  - in Österreich: [ˈa͡e]
  - in Deutschland: [ˈa͡e]
  - in der Schweiz: [ˈa͡ɪ]

Wie man sieht, umgeht Wikipedia eine Festlegung, indem dort anstelle von [Phonen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phon_(Linguistik)), die man an den eckigen Klammern erkennt, [Phoneme](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonem) (zwischen zwei Schrägstrichen) notiert sind.

Unterschiedlich ist auch, dass Wiktionary und Wikipedia den Diphthong mit einem » ̯
« unter dem zweiten Laut kennzeichnen, während die Aussprachedatenbank stattdessen eine Betonung des ersten Lautes anzeigt und beide Laute mit einem Ligaturbogen verbindet. Aber das sind letzen Endes nur unterschiedliche Schreibweisen für denselben Sachverhalt. (Eine verbindliche Orthographie für Lautschrift scheint es leider nicht zu geben.)

Das, was mich aber stutzig macht, ist der zweite Laut des Diphthongs, der in diesen beiden Varianten notiert ist:

- [ɪ] (wie das i in »Ärztin«)
- [e] (wie das erste e in »lebendig«)

Vor allen die Adaba ist in dieser Sache interessant, weil sie angibt, dass »Ei« nur in der Schweiz mit [ɪ] gesprochen wird, während im restlichen deutschen Sprachraum laut dieser Quelle nur [e] in Verwendung zu sein scheint. Gleichzeitig behauptet aber Wiktionary, dass überall (nicht nur in der Schweiz) [ɪ] richtig sein soll. Diese beiden Quellen widersprechen einander also.

**Meine Fragen:**

Beruht die unterschiedliche Notierung des zweiten Lautes des Diphthongs »ei« darauf, dass [e] und [ɪ] Allophone sind, also zwei Laute, die man beliebig gegeneinander austauschen kann? Oder liegt in einer der Quellen ein Fehler vor? Wenn ja in welcher? (Ich persönlich kann mich nicht entscheiden, ob »Ei« eher als [aɪ] oder [ae] gesprochen wird.)

Würde es auffallen, wenn jemand einen weiblichen Arzt »Ärzt**e**n« nennen würde (also [ˈɛʁʦten] statt [ˈɛʁʦtɪn]) (nicht gemeint ist [ˈɛʁʦtn̩], der Plural-Dativ von »Arzt«). Fällt es auf, wenn jemand »l**i**bendig« ([lɪˈbɛndɪç] statt [leˈbɛndɪç]) sagt?

Oder gibt es ein [e]/[ɪ]-[Minimalpaar](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimalpaar), dass belegen würde, dass diese beiden Laute zu zwei eigenständigen Phonemen gehören? Was ist in diesem Fall davon zu halten, dass der Diphthong »ei« einmal als [aɪ], ein andermal aber als [ae] notiert ist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Systematische Unsicherheit im IPA

Grundsätzlich sind [e] und [ɪ] in IPA als zwei verschiedene Laute definiert. Allerdings gibt es kaum Sprachen, die im Bereich der i- und e-Laute mehr als drei verschiedene Qualitäten unterscheiden (die meisten Sprachen unterscheiden höchstens zwei Qualitäten, also genau einen i-Laut und einen e-Laut)

- Das Französische etwa hat zwei e-Laute (/e/ und /ɛ/), aber nur einen i-Laut (/i/).
- Die westlichen schweizerdeutschen Dialekte etwa haben zwei i-Laute (/i/ und /ɪ/), aber nur einen e-Laut (/ɛ/).
- Gemäss der Analyse von Moulton gibt es in der Ostschweiz einige Gebiete (etwa im oberen Toggenburg), die tatsächlich einen vierfachen Gegensatz mit je zwei i- und zwei e-Lauten aufweisen, aber ein derartiges letztlich fünfstufiges Vokalsystem scheint extrem selten zu sein. Wenn du also ein echtes Minimalpaar zwischen /ɪ/ und /e/ finden wolltest, dann müsstest du dort suchen. Das /e/ tritt etwa im Wort *Vetter* auf, das /ɪ/ hingegen im Wort *Schlitten* (vgl. Moulton, William G. (1960): “[The short vowel systems of Northern Switzerland](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00437956.1960.11659724)”. In: *Word* 37, S. 155–182).

Unsere Schrift hat grundsätzlich nur zwei Zeichen, nämlich *i* und *e.* Der Versuch, mit dieser Schrift einen dreifachen Unterschied innerhalb der i- und e-Laute zu schreiben, führt also zu einer systematischen Unklarheit beim mittleren Laut. Es ist unklar, ob er nun eher zum i-Lager gehört oder zum e-Lager. Ein schönes Beispiel dafür finden wir in den westlichen schweizerdeutschen Dialekten: Der mittlere Vokal, der weder ein geschlossenes /i/ noch ein offenes /ɛ/ ist, wird in Luzern traditionell eher als ein geschlossener e-Vokal identifiziert *(met, Bleck),* in Bern oder Basel hingegen eher als ein offener i-Vokal *(mit, Blick).* So entsteht der falsche Eindruck, es gäbe einen deutlichen Unterschied zwischen *Bleck* und *Blick,* obwohl es in Wahrheit gar keinen oder höchstens einen minimalen Unterschied gibt.

Es ist unklar, warum das IPA überhaupt vier verschiedene Zeichen für die i- und e-Laute vorsieht ([i ɪ e ɛ]). Das Obertoggenburgische ist bestimmt nicht der Grund dafür. Ich vermute, der Grund könnte darin liegen, dass der mittlere Vokal im Französischen mit einem *e* identifiziert ist (vgl. Wörter wie *été* usw.), im Englischen hingegen mit einem *i* (vgl. Wörter wie *bit* usw.). Um dem Englischen nicht die französische Assoziation des mittleren Lauts mit einem *e* aufzuzwingen, hätte man also das Zeichen [ɪ] gewissermassen als Kompromiss geschaffen – es wäre also einfach ein alternatives [e] für diejenigen Fälle, wo die Assoziation mit dem *i* besonders stark ist. So ganz richtig ins IPA integriert ist das Zeichen [ɪ] allerdings nicht. Es ist keiner der acht [Kardinalvokale](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kardinalvokal) (die übrigens einfach den französischen Vokalen entsprechen) und es steht irgendwie krumm im [Vokaltrapez](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vokaltrapez).

## Standarddeutsch

Das Standarddeutsche hat den mittleren Vokal zwischen *i* und *e* gewissermassen doppelt, einmal assoziiert mit dem *i* und einmal mit dem *e.* Im System der langen Vokale haben wir die drei Vokale /iː eː ɛː/. Hier ist der mittlere Vokal mit dem *e* assoziiert (vgl. Wörter wie *Dehnung, See).* Im System der kurzen Vokale haben wir zwar nur zwei Vokale. Der geschlossenere dieser beiden Vokale ist phonetisch gesehen ein mittlerer Vokal. Wir geben ihn aber nicht mit /e/ wider, sondern /ɪ/, denn er ist mit dem *i* assoziiert (vgl. Wörter wie *mit, Blick).* In einer einfacheren Welt, wo das IPA nur die Kardinalvokale enthielte und nicht mit Kompromiss-Zwischenvokalen wie dem [ɪ] angereichert worden wäre, würden wir diesen Vokal selbstverständlich als /e/ schreiben.

Was die Vokalformanten angeht, so ist das deutsche /eː/ vom deutschen /ɪ/ nicht zu unterscheiden. Oft wird zwar ein Unterschied in der Gespanntheit postuliert, aber phonetisch gesehen handelt es sich dabei um eine unklare Grösse. Es ist unklar, was Gespanntheit artikulatorisch gesehen denn eigentlich ist und wie sie sich akustisch ausdrückt, und dementsprechend ist auch nicht klar, wie man sie denn nachweisen sollte.

Ob man nun das deutsche *ei* als [aɪ] oder als [ae] schreibt, ist eine reine Konvention. Persönlich halte ich die Schreibung [ae] eher für verwirrend, denn der zweite Laut des Diphthongs ist ja im Deutschen gar nicht mit dem *e* assoziiert, sondern mit dem *i.* Wir schreiben den Diphthong als *ei* oder *ai*, und nicht etwa – wie im Lateinischen – als *ae.* Wenn man trotz der Assoziierung mit dem *i* nicht das Zeichen [ɪ] verwendet, sondern das Zeichen [e], dann sollte man eine ganz besonders stichhaltige und überzeugende Begründung haben.

Im Nebentonvokalismus ist die Sache naturgemäss weniger klar. Ich vermute mal, dass deine Annahme, das Wort *lebendig* hätte ein [e], nicht so einfach ist. Das Wort können wir wohl als /(ˌ)leːˈbɛndɪɡ/ analysieren, wobei dann die Aussprache des nebentonigen /eː/ zwischen [eˑ], [e], [ɛ] und [ə] schwanken dürfte – und von mir aus eben auch [ɪ], wenn man unterstellt, dass ein [ɪ] nichts weiter ist als ein [e] mit starker Assoziation zu einem *i.*

Comment: Darf ich aus deiner Antwort schließen, dass die kurzen unbetonten Vokale [e] und [ɪ] eigentlich identisch, zumindest aber im Deutschen Allophone sind, und dass die Wahl des konkreten Zeichens in der Lautschrift weniger von der tatsächlichen Aussprache beeinflusst wird (welche ja durch die Lautschrift wiedergeben sollte), sondern viel mehr von der Schreibung (welche auf die Wahl der Lautschriftzeichen zumindest meiner Auffassung nach eigentlich gar keinen Einfluss haben sollte)?

Comment: Ja, das ist in etwa meine Aussage, nur dass das Wort [Allophon](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allophon) etwas ganz anders bedeutet und nicht in diesen Zusammenhang passt.